# Task.Run() to execute a thread? Does it improve performance?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, task, threadpool

I am trying to look for an answer for the following.
Does it make sense to

```
var task_VeryLongTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Work_Verylongprocess1());
    thread1.Start();
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => Work_Verylongprocess1());
    thread2.Start();
    //...more threads until 10
});
```

Does this actually improve performance or it something that is redundant?

Comment: No, it's not making sense. You use Task.Run to spin up a background thread. Then in the newly spun up background thread, you create threads, but this time you are not using Task.Run(), but rather Thread.Start(), which is highly unusual. "_Does this actually improve performance [...]?_" Maybe, or perhaps the opposite. It entirely depends on what each thread is supposed to do and to which degree and in which manner the threads will concurrently access shared resources. The TL;DR is basically: Based on the little information you have given, your question is not answerable...

Comment: In general, unless you're really confident about the hardware your application is going to run on, mixing and matching Tasks and Threads isn't a stellar idea.  If you want 10 tasks to run in parallel and want control over the parallelism, use `Parallel.ForEach`.  If you just want .NET to take the wheel, kick off a bunch of tasks.  If you need find grained control over the way in which each thread behaves while running, you can start a bunch of threads, but don't use tasks to start threads.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to do that. Starting a `Thread` is not a CPU intensive or high-latency operation. It completes in a matter of microseconds. So offloading this minuscule work to a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread (that's what the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) does) is not likely to offer any benefit to your application. It might even be detrimental in case the `ThreadPool` is currently saturated, in which case the threads will not get started immediately. Using the `Task.Run` also gives you the obligation to `await` or `Wait` the resulting `Task`, in order to observe possible exceptions thrown while starting the threads. If you let the task run in a fire-and-forget fashion, then your program might suddenly stop working, without giving to the user any indication that something has gone wrong.

Comment: Also I would add that starting threads manually is rarely needed in modern .NET apps and usually should be delegated to `Task` API. Especially if there are questions arising like one in the original post)

Comment: @GuruStron I agree in general. But starting a new `Task` that wraps a dedicated `Thread` is not less code than starting a new `Thread` directly. So if you don't need the extra functionality that comes with a `Task`, like the ability to `await` it and handle the exceptions at the `await` point, you might as well go with the `Thread` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer about threadpool saturation, that even if the threadpool is not saturated, you don't want to block an entire thread from the threadpool for a long running non-async operation.

However, instead of threads, you can use the [LongRunning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-taskcreationoptions-longrunning) option when creating your task via `StartNew` or the `Task` constructor.